# Find xpath tag not in specified path

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

Is it possible using `Nokogiri::XML.xpath`, or any other XML parser to find tags that are outside the specified path?

For instance.  If I have the following XML:

```
<root>
  <bar>baz</bar>
  <foo>
    <bar>baz</bar>
  </foo>
</root>
```

I know that bar will always exist inside of foo, but it may also exist outside of foo, and not necessarily in the same place everytime, is there a way to search for that kind of condition with xpath?  I know you can do `xml.xpath("//bar")` and it will return all instances of bar, but I need to be able to know the parent object that bar exists in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
xml.xpath('//bar[not(ancestor::foo)]')
```

This selects all `bar` elements that are not *anywhere* under a `foo` element. (This is different than the assumption Dimitre made, but you haven't specified either way)

For the provided XML document, this selects just one element: the `bar` under root.

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
//*[not(self::foo) and bar]
```

This selects all  elements in the XML document that are not `foo` and that have a child `bar`.

For the provided XML document, this selects just one element -- `root`.